# Segmentation fault in Assembly when trying to double the array

Tags: arrays, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

i've been trying to fix this for like 5 hours. I'm trying to get it so that after 5 elements are entered into the array then the array doubles and copies the old elements into the new and continues until you stop and then it outputs the stats, for some reason after entering 5 numbersIi just get a segmentation fault

```
 %define ARRAY_SIZE  5
   %define ELEMENT_SIZE 4
   %define EOF -1
   
segment .data
   inputPrompt: db "Enter int value (ctrl-d to stop): ",0
   intFormat:   db "%d",0
   output:      db "Array[%d] = %d",10,0
   dbout:       db 10, 10,"[%d]",10,10,0 ; This is just for debugging output
   newline:     db 10,0                  ; For whenever we need a newline
   numElements: db "Number of elements: %d",10,0
   outputSum:   db "sum of elements: %d",10,0
   minValue:    db "Min value: %d",10,0
   maxValue:    db "Max value: %d",10,0

segment .bss
   arrayPtr:  resq 1                     ; pointer to our array
   intInput:  resd 1

segment .text
   global asm_main
   extern printf, scanf, calloc
   
createNewArray:
   mov   rdi, [arrayPtr]
   mov   rsi, ARRAY_SIZE
   add   rsi, rsi            ; Double the array size
   mov   rdx, ELEMENT_SIZE
   call  calloc
   mov   rbx, [arrayPtr]     ; Move the old array elements to the new array
   mov   rcx, ARRAY_SIZE
   cld
   rep   movsd
   mov   [arrayPtr], rax     ; Save the new array pointer
   ret  
   
asm_main:
   enter 0,0

   ;; Get memory for our array
   ;; Give calloc() number of element and element size
   ;; and calloc returns a pointer to zerioized memory
   mov   rdi, ARRAY_SIZE
   mov   rsi, ELEMENT_SIZE
   call  calloc
   mov   [arrayPtr], rax
   
   mov   rdi, [arrayPtr]        ; Will use RDI and stosd to write the array
   mov   rcx, ARRAY_SIZE
   mov   r15, 0                 ; R15 counts how many elements in our array
   cld
inputLoop:
   push  rcx                    ; Save RCX and RDI across printf/scanf calls
   push  rdi
   mov   rdi, inputPrompt
   call  printf

   mov   rdi, intFormat
   mov   rsi, intInput
   call  scanf

   cmp   eax, EOF               ; Did scanf() return -1 (didn't read anything?)
   je    inputDone
   inc   r15                    ; O/w count another element & store it
   
   cmp   r15, ARRAY_SIZE        ; Check if we've filled up the current array
   jl    arrayNotFull           ; O/w, create a new array
   call  createNewArray
   mov   rdi, [arrayPtr]        ; Update the pointers and sizes
   mov   rcx, r15
   
arrayNotFull:
   
   xor   rax, rax               ; Clear out RAX for stosd to write array to mem
   mov   eax, [intInput]
   pop   rdi                    ; Restore RDI for stosd
   stosd
   pop   rcx                    ; Restore RCS for loop instruction
   loop  inputLoop
   
inputDone:                      ; Let's get ready to print
   mov   rdi, newline
   call  printf
   mov   rsi, [arrayPtr]        ; Will use RSI and lodsd to read the array
   mov   rcx, r15               ; Store actual array size to RCX
   mov   rbx, 0
   cld
printLoop:
   xor   rax, rax
   xor   rdx, rdx
   lodsd
   push  rcx                    ; Save RCX and RSI across printf call
   push  rsi
   mov   rdi, output
   mov   rsi, rbx

   movsx rdx, eax
   call  printf
   inc   rbx

   pop   rsi                    ; Restore RCX and RSI
   pop   rcx
   loop  printLoop
   je    printStats
   
printStats:
   mov   rdi, newline
   call  printf
   mov   rdi, numElements
   mov   rsi, r15
   call  printf
   
   mov   rax, 0         ; Initialize the sum to zero
   mov   rsi, [arrayPtr] ; Get the address of the array
   mov   rcx, r15        ; Store actual array size to RCX
   cld
   
   xor   rdx, rdx       ; Clear out RDX for the first add instruction
   
   mov   rax, 0           ; Initialize the sum to zero
   mov   rsi, [arrayPtr]  ; Get the address of the array
   mov   rcx, r15         ; Store actual array size to RCX
   cld
sumLoop:
   lodsd                  ; Load the next element of the array into EAX
   add   rax, r8          ; Add the current sum to EAX
   mov   r8, rax          ; Store the updated sum in R8
   loop  sumLoop
   mov   rdi, outputSum
   mov   rsi, r8
   call  printf
   
 ; Find the minimum value in the array
   mov   rax, [arrayPtr]     ; Load the base address of the array into RAX
   mov   ebx, [rax]          ; Load the first element of the array into EBX
   mov   rcx, r15            ; Loop counter will be the number of elements
   dec   rcx                 ; Decrement RCX since we've already loaded the first element
   mov   rsi, [rax]          ; Initialize RSI to the first element
loopStart:
   add   rax, ELEMENT_SIZE   ; Move the pointer to the next element
   cmp   [rax], ebx          ; Compare the value at the current pointer to the minimum value
   jge   loopEnd             ; If the value is greater than or equal to the minimum, skip to the end of the loop
   mov   ebx, [rax]          ; Otherwise, update the minimum value
   mov   rsi, rax            ; and store the address of the minimum value in RSI
loopEnd:
   loop  loopStart           ; Repeat for the remaining elements of the array
   mov   rdi, minValue
   mov   rsi, rbx
   call  printf

; Find the maximum value in the array
   mov   rax, [arrayPtr]     ; Load the base address of the array into RAX
   mov   ebx, [rax]          ; Load the first element of the array into EBX
   mov   rcx, r15            ; Loop counter will be the number of elements
   dec   rcx                 ; Decrement RCX since we've already loaded the first element
   mov   rsi, [rax]          ; Initialize RSI to the first element
loopStartd:
   add   rax, ELEMENT_SIZE   ; Move the pointer to the next element
   cmp   [rax], ebx          ; Compare the value at the current pointer to the maximum value
   jle   loopEndd             ; If the value is less than or equal to the maximum, skip to the end of the loop
   mov   ebx, [rax]          ; O/w, update the maximum value to the current value
   mov   rsi, rax            ; Store the address of the current maximum value
loopEndd:
   loop  loopStartd
   mov   rdi, maxValue
   mov   rsi, rbx
   call  printf

   mov   rax, 0
   leave 
   ret
```

I tried to save the new array pointer [arrayPtr], rax but it doesn't seem to do anything or I am doing something wrong, any help would be great.

Comment: check if your `esi` & `edi` are correctly set for `rep movsd` in `createNewArray`

Comment: Unfortunately no luck there

Comment: You haven't shared what instruction gets the seg fault, or the register contents at the time.  Why not do basic debugging using single step?  Get to know your data so you know what good addresses look like.  Seg faults are about some instruction in the code using a bad address.

Answer (score 1):

How does *calloc* work? The registers aren't used in a consistent manner.

The first time (in *main*) you use it like:

> ```
> mov   rdi, ARRAY_SIZE
> mov   rsi, ELEMENT_SIZE
> call  calloc   ; -> RAX
> ```

But the second time (in *createNewArray*) you use it like:

> ```
> mov   rdi, [arrayPtr]
> mov   rsi, ARRAY_SIZE
> add   rsi, rsi            ; Double the array size
> mov   rdx, ELEMENT_SIZE
> call  calloc   ; -> RAX
> ```

---

The `rep movsd` that follows is neither given a suitable RSI nor RDI. The reason for the segmentation fault...

> ```
> mov   rbx, [arrayPtr]     ; Move the old array elements to the new array
> mov   rcx, ARRAY_SIZE
> cld
> rep   movsd
> mov   [arrayPtr], rax     ; Save the new array pointer
> ```

---

In the *inputLoop* you are calling *createNewArray* even before having stored the fifth array element in the first array. That's another reason for your above mentioned `rep movsd` to not function correctly.
Shouldn't you wait until *inputDone* before wanting to create a second array?

---

### Maybe an idea

If you know that you are going to duplicate the array anyway, why not allocate double the memory to begin with in *main*, and then store to both arrays at once:

```
mov   eax, [intInput]
pop   rdi                                   ; Restore RDI for stosd
mov   [rdi + ELEMENT_SIZE * ARRAYSIZE], eax ; Store in 2nd array
stosd                                       ; Store in 1st array
```

Comment: calloc takes 2 size_t args and returns a pointer (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), following the x86-64 System V ABI's calling convention (args in RDI, RSI).  Apparently there is a function that works like their second call, documented in the same glibc man page, but it's called `reallocarray`, a `realloc` with the size specified the way `calloc` works.  (First appeared in OpenBSD / FreeBSD, now supported in GNU systems, unlike `calloc` / `realloc` which are ISO C89.)

Comment: Sorry I am extremely new to assembly, I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around the main cause of the segment error and how I would change it to fix it